# How to print Smalltalk code from Pharo/Squeak?

Tags: printing, syntax-highlighting, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

What is the best way to print - syntax colored and well formatted - code from Pharo/Squeak on paper?

1) Is there a way to print directly from within Pharo/Squeak? (i use it on macosx)
2) Is there a way to export syntax colored, well formatted code from Pharo/Squak? 
3) Are there external tools to color and format a filed out piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the appendix in my [master thesis](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/masters/Reng06a.pdf) I used the [Pier CMS](http://www.piercms.com)-to-LaTeX converter in the `Pier-Documentation` package. However, this plugin only takes class comments and method comments into consideration, it does not print the source code. Pier also provides a package `ShoutPier` for syntax highlighting of Smalltalk code, so I guess it would require little work to bring the two together. You can find the mentioned extension packages in http://source.lukas-renggli.ch/pieraddons.html.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get some nice printouts using PRLatexBuilder.

Comment: Nevertheless i hoped something like this would be a common task and built into the standard system.. But it seems people don’t print code on paper so often?

Comment: Earlier versions of Squeak (around version 3.0) had a HTML exporter similar to the file-out mechanism still present today. I guess that could have worked for printing. It was removed at some point because nobody used it and it broke over time.

Answer (score 1):

[Pharo browsers seem to use syntax highlighting.](http://www.pharo-project.org/about/screenshots)

What difficulty are you having reading Smalltalk code using the browsers and senders/implementors ?

Edit:  Would something that produces UML [give the overview you're looking for](http://www.mars.dti.ne.jp/~umejava/images/MagicDrawDandelion1.jpg)? The Dandelion website only shows [downloads for old Squeak versions](http://www.mars.dti.ne.jp/~umejava/smalltalk/stClasses/dandelion/) - I don't know if they would work with Pharo.

And perhaps this GSoC project ["Generate UML diagrams from Smalltalk code for Pharo"](http://gsoc2010.esug.org/projects/uml-from-smalltalk) suggests not.

Comment: The Pharo browsers are good. It’s just my desk is so much bigger than my screen - so i can have a look at so much more code at once - and i think it’s easier to get the „big picture“.
At the moment i print screenshots from the Pharo browser for each class - this gives me something in the spirit of crc-cards (http://c2.com/doc/crc/draw.html)

Comment: @roy-fleming - I was never even slightly tempted to do that with Smalltalk so it's quite puzzling to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it on my Mac, I think this should work on other platforms too.

1. Save your categories to a Monticello local folder on your disk -- see the Pharo manual on how to do this: http://book.pharo-project.org/book/PharoTools/Monticello/?_s=hdGOLc_FXsvVY1iR&_k=YYH-Ln8f5mtWZ8z2&_n&148
2. Browse to this folder, and unzip the .mcz file
3. You'll see all your code in snapshot/source.st file
4. You'll need to edit this a bit, to remove the ! characters for e.g., there might be a tool to do this?

-Eric.

Comment: A slightly simpler method: in Pharo you can use File Out on a class and this will generate a .st file (on my Mac I have to open the Pharo package contents to find this file), then proceed with step 4 above.

Answer (score 1):

There is webdoc project, which allows you navigating code in web browser:
http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/webdoc.html
(and of course you can print code from your favorite web browser)..

Answer (score 0):

1) Install shout from www.squeaksource.com

2) I don't know. May be you can customize shout.

3) In gnu-smalltalk you have a smalltalk mode for emacs. But I am not pretty sure to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I’m looking for a way to read smalltalk code. And i wanted to print it on paper (the question was not about „pretty-print“ in the smalltalk-browser).